# Testing concurrency with Typescript/JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, concurrency

I'm working on a TS application and I need to test some concurrent code and how it interacts with a database (the code deals with idepotency). I want to verify that multiple requests that modify the same resource would apply the changes correctly or fail, rather than experience lost updates or processing them twice.

I quite a lot of experience testing this in Java (as it has a ton of concurrency primitives like semaphores, barriers, and other things to control concurrency and parallelism), but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this in TS.

For example, in Java I would start 2 threads passing a `CyclicBarrier` with 2 parties. Both threads would execute up to the barrier, wait for eachother, and then continue. In this way I could often ensure that the code worked as expected. If I couldn't ensure 100% that the code would be run in parallel, I would run the same time multiple times or with more threads to increase the chances of parallel execution.

I cannot find any concurrency primitives in JS that would allow me to do something similar. The best I've found is to do a busy wait on a shared value. Some blogs suggest to use worker threads.

Any suggestions how this is usually done? This is a difficult topic, so links to blogs, articles & books are appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "I need to test some concurrent code": is it an imported library you need to test, or an external service?  And, in any case, what is the API it exposes (e.g. what is the signature of at least one representative method)?

Comment: It's a small library I'm writing to handle idempotency; later it will be used to process web requests and queues. The library performs a few SQL operations and needs to handle a bunch of scenarios in which the same operation is tried concurrently.

Comment: Use DB transactions to handle db operation concurencies. This is why they are made for. Set the right transaction level to suit your needs

Comment: Hi @SvetoslavPetkov , the code uses the DB to handle the concurrency as there are multiple instances of the service running, but needs to be tested to ensure it works as expected. The tests I'm running are integration tests connecting to a database instance (no test doubles are used).

Comment: @Augusto , you can for test purposes put somewhere in the transaction a sleep to make it long runnning. If you use postgress you can use `pg_sleep`. And then invoke the api two times trying to modify the same resource (row) using postman or curl or wget. This is how you can test it.

begin transaction;

read something;

pg sleep ;

update;

commit transaction

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `pg_sleep`. I wasn't aware of it and I'm sure it will become very handy. Back to the question, I want to create automated tests as I want to keep my ability to deploy to production a few times a day.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to point out, that as opposed to Java or other languages, JS (TS in this case) is single threaded. Meaning that only one line of TS/JS is running at the same time. There are ways around this (like WebWorkers) but I will assume you are not using them in this case.

In case you plan to use your library in any environment where there are two instances of your application running, you have two truly parallel systems. For the first part, I will assume this is not the case.

**Testing concurrency in a single node process**

In this case it is quite simple, and it all relies on the JS event loop. There  is a great talk by Philip Roberts on this topic from JSConf.

With a single node process and (I assume) "async" functions, Promises are executed concurrently. However, the yielding (letting other code run) of the async function, happens when you do some async operation (IO, web request etc...)

The simplest way to test your library in this case is perhaps doing:

```
function test() {
    Promise.all([
        doSomething(),
        doSomething(),
    ]);
}
```

**Testing concurrency in a multi process environment**

Perhaps your application is running on multiple machines at the same time. In this case it complicates things quite a lot. We cannot easily test this, mostly because we can't just start a test which will directly call the function. We will need to start two processes and call them "at the same time".

I would highly advise against doing something like this, if the operation you are testing is pretty fast, it may result in flaky tests. It is really hard to make sure that things execute at exactly the same time.

Perhaps a better solution would be to introduce an artificial delay. Make critical section take quite a bit of time (a few seconds maybe) and call both instances one after another. You can also `Promise.all()` the calls to get maximum concurrency. Although that is not really an issue, if the critical section takes a few seconds. This way you are sure that things don't misbehave.

I will leave the "spawning and calling two processes" part up to you. You can create a web worker, which in node creates a new V8 execution context. Or make a simple http server and send it through that.

**In case you don't like the second solution**

I don't know of anything much more parallel then `Promise.all` by the whole nature of JS being single-threaded. The simplest solution would probably be to have a small script written in something else to test this behavior. I don't know much Java, but in Rust the concurrency primitives are very good. Although then the "calling JS" part becomes a bit harder.

Comment: Hi Juraj. This will be used in applications that run on multiple instances, so it's the second scenario that you mentioned. So far, I'm running multiple async functions and using a `Promise.all` to collect the results (same as what you suggested). I was able to trigger scenarios that the library needs to handle (e.g. one transaction succeds, the other fails but it's retried). I couldn't make it reproducible in a single test run, so I've configured Jest to run the same test multiple times which gives me a bit more confidence that the test will trigger the scenario.

Comment: @Augusto yes, your solution will work. And if you are using Jest, you can only use the native JS primitives (like Promise.all) to run things at the same time. Although it may be worth considering some external synchronization, with something like Unix pipes or waiting for specific time with something like `process.hrtime` (I have never used these techniques)